# c# mono httplistener does not write http-headers

Tags: c#, .net, mono, http-headers, httplistener

I've got a simple web server that I want to run on linux using mono. Everything works fine on windows using the .net framework but when I try to run the same application in mono it doesn't behave as expected.

I'm using `mono 4.6.1.5 x64` and `.net 4.5.2 x64`

So when sending a request to the server running in .net the returned response is:

**.net**

headers

```
Request URL:http://localhost:4040/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:4040
Response Headers
view source
Content-Length:9
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 03 Nov 2016 08:23:16 GMT
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

preview

```
test data
```

---

then when I'm running the same build using mono the server log show the response finishing immediately while the browser is loading for 10 seconds before showing a response. The response now is:

**mono**

headers

```
Request URL:http://localhost:4040/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:4040
```

preview

```
P/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Mono-HTTPAPI/1.0
Date: Thu, 03 Nov 2016 08:25:10 GMT
Content-Length: 9
Keep-Alive: timeout=15,max=100

test data
```

---

**code**

main listener loop

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:4040/");
listener.Start();
while (true)
{
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
    Console.WriteLine ("Proccessing {0}", context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
    Process (context);
    Console.WriteLine ("Proccessing complete");
}
```

processing code

```
private void Process(HttpListenerContext context)
{
    string data = "test data";
    WriteResponse(context.Response, data, HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

private void WriteResponse (HttpListenerResponse response, string data, HttpStatusCode status)
{
    response.StatusCode = (int)status;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
    {
        response.ContentType = "text/html";
        response.ContentLength64 = data.Length;

        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(data);
        response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, data.Length);
        response.OutputStream.Flush();
    }

    response.Close ();
}
```

I tried to use [nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) standalone application and there I'm having the same problem so I'm thinking its something wrong in mono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently it's a bug in mono that is still not fixed ([bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=30065)). As seen in the preview example:

```
P/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Mono-HTTPAPI/1.0
Date: Thu, 03 Nov 2016 08:25:10 GMT
Content-Length: 9
Keep-Alive: timeout=15,max=100

test data
```

the first 3 characters of the http response are missing.

So the problem is more an incorrect http response then just missing headers. As far as I know there also are no workarounds, please correct me if I'm wrong.